# Using lombok with gradle and spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, lombok

I am trying to build a project with lombok and this is what I have as dependencie.

```
dependencies {
   compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
   compile("org.springframework.social:spring-social-facebook")
   compile("org.springframework.social:spring-social-twitter")
   testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
   testCompile("junit:junit")
   compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
   compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
   compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
   compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.10")
}
```

I am able to include the anotations, and I have included lombok in the editor. I am even able to compile a code using lombok and making a cal to a method generated by lombok.

This is my entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEA_USER", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "USR_EMAIL" }),
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "USR_NAME" })
})
public class User {


   @NotNull
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name="USR_ID")
   private long id;

   @NotNull
   @Column(name="USR_FNAME")
   private String firstName;

   @NotNull
   @Column(name="USR_LNAME")
   private String lastName;


   @NotNull
   @Min(5)
   @Max(30)
   @Column(name="USR_NAME")
   private String username;

   @Column(name="USR_EMAIL")
   private String email;

   @Min(8)
   @NotNull
   @Column(name="USR_PASSWORD")
   private String password;
}
```

And this is a function that compiles fine:

```
@PostMapping("/registration/register")
public String doRegister (@ModelAttribute @Valid User user, BindingResult result){
    user.getEmail();
    System.out.println(user.getFirstName());
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
         return "register/customRegister";
    }
    this.userRepository.save(user);
    return "register/customRegistered";
}
```

But when I run bootRun and I try to access the funcionality this is the Exception I get:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'firstName' of bean class [com.lucasfrossard.entities.User]: Bean property 'firstName' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

But, if I manually include the setter and getters, this works fine. I don't get whats going on and how to fix it. Any idea?

Answer (score 43):

With the latest Lombok 1.18 it's simple. `io.franzbecker.gradle-lombok` plugin is not required. Example dependencies from my project:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf"
    implementation "org.springframework.social:spring-social-facebook"
    implementation "org.springframework.social:spring-social-twitter"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"

    testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test"

    runtimeClasspath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools"
    runtime "mysql:mysql-connector-java"

    // https://projectlombok.org
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
}
```

Other suggestions:

1. `testCompile("junit:junit")` is not required because the `spring-boot-starter-test` “Starter” [contains JUnit](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html).
2. Use `implementation` or `api` configuration instead of `compile` (since [Gradle 3.4](https://docs.gradle.org/3.4/release-notes.html)). [How do I choose the right one?](http://www.davidwong.com.au/blog/2018/03/gradle-dependencies-for-java-use-compile-or-implementation/)
3. Do not use `compile` configuration for `devtools`. A tip from [Developer Tools](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html) guide:

   > Flagging the dependency as optional in Maven or using a custom `developmentOnly` configuration in Gradle (as shown above) is a best practice that prevents devtools from being transitively applied to other modules that use your project.
4. If you use IntelliJ IDEA, make sure you have [Lombok plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok-plugin) installed and [Annotation Processing](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-annotation-processing.html) enabled. To make an initial project setup easier for newcomers you can also specify the Lombok plugin as [required](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/required-plugin.html).

Comment: Thank you.
annotationProcessor  'org.projectlombok:lombok' fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 16):

After struggling with this for a while I found this plugin would do the trick:

https://github.com/franzbecker/gradle-lombok

My gradle file just looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone" }
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.0.RELEASE")
        classpath 'org.springframework:springloaded:1.2.6.RELEASE'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'io.franzbecker.gradle-lombok' version '1.8'
    id 'java'
}



apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'



jar {
    baseName = 'gs-accessing-facebook'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone" }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    // compile("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.10")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile("org.springframework.social:spring-social-facebook")
    compile("org.springframework.social:spring-social-twitter")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
}

idea {
    module {
        inheritOutputDirs = false
        outputDir = file("$buildDir/classes/main/")
    }
}

bootRun {
    addResources = true
    jvmArgs "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"
}
```

I had come across this plugin before but I did something wrong and it didn't work. I am glad it worked now.

Thanks!

Comment: We are also having this setup and there is no need for having an additional plugin. Which IDE are you using? You should install the plugin for you IDE I guess? https://projectlombok.org/download.html

Comment: This plugin helped me a lot, thank you!
Can you please explain why it happens? In maven project it is enough to add a <dependency> with lombok, but here, in gradle, we need some weird plugin instead of that.

Comment: It is probably because the plugin automatically activates java compiler's annotation processing. It supposedly has nothing to do with the actual running of the code, lombok does things compile type only. However, I'm not sure that using the plugin is really necessary with the most recent versions of gradle/lombok

Comment: Confirmed, didn't need the plugin here, just included compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2' as a dependency. Using gradle 4.5.1 in this project.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using `Eclipse` or one of its offshoots(I am using Spring Tool Suite `4.5.1.RELEASE`, - the same steps apply for any other release), all that you need to do is:

- In `build.gradle`:

  ```
  dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'  
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
  }
  ```
- Then, right-click on your project > Gradle > Refresh Gradle Project. The `lombok-"version".jar` will *appear* inside your project's **Project and External Dependencies**
- Right-click on that `lombok-"version".jar` > Run As > Java Application (similar to double-clicking on the actual jar or running `java -jar lombok-"version".jar` on the command line.)
- A GUI will appear, follow all the instructions and one of the thing it does is, it copies `lombok.jar` to your IDE's root folder.

**Note: Remember to restart your IDE and clean all your previously compiled files.**