# Gradle build fails due to lombok

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, lombok

I'm using Gradle 4.10.2 (but would be fine using the latest version to get it to work).  Here's my gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.5.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "Hoxton.SR3")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```

When I execute `bootJar`, it fails with a lot of errors. The errors are all due to not finding getters, setters, etc. that are auto generated by lombok. How can I resolve the errors? I've seen other posts about this issue and they all recommend adding the lombok dependency as a `annotationProcessor` & `compileOnly` but I've already done this and still have this issue.

**Update**

Here are a couple of errors that I get:

```
C:\Users\user\eclipse-workspace\example\src\main\java\com\example\proj\service\CarService.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
            log.debug("calling for cars {} ", cars);
            ^
  symbol:   variable log
  location: class CarService
C:\Users\user\eclipse-workspace\example\src\main\java\com\example\proj\service\CarService.java:66: error: cannot find symbol
                CarDtoBuilder dtoBuilder = dtoBuilderByCar.getOrDefault(
                ^
  symbol:   class CarDtoBuilder
  location: class CarService
```

log should come from annotation `@Slf4j`. And the `CarDtoBuilder` is from `@Builder(builderMethodName = "hiddenBuild")` annotated on CarDto. Both are lombok annotations.

**Update 2**

Now trying Gradle 4.10.3. Same result. Here's output from `gradle -v`:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.10.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-12-05 00:50:54 UTC
Revision:     e76905e3a1034e6f724566aeb985621347ff43bc

Kotlin DSL:   1.0-rc-6
Kotlin:       1.2.61
Groovy:       2.4.15
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.11 compiled on March 23 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_222 ( 25.222-b10)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

**Update 3**

I've tried this using Gradle 6 same result. I've tried using Windows and Mac... same result. I've tried using JDK 11 instead of JDK 8... same result.

**Update 4**

I'm using `@Builder` lombok annotation. I wonder if that is causing an issue.

Comment: Try this if you're using Eclipse/Eclipse based IDE - https://www.journaldev.com/18124/java-project-lombok

Comment: I'm using Eclipse and BuildShip. Everything compiles fine using the IDE and the Boot Dashboard. It fails only when issuing `bootJar` using BuildShip

Comment: I just tried at the command line using `gradle bootJar` and same issue.

Comment: Which version of Lombok is used?  With the latest version 1.18 it should work. Otherwise there are more recommendations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40475910/using-lombok-with-gradle-and-spring-boot).

Comment: @flaxel - Lombok v1.18.12. Thanks for the link. Taking a look now.

Comment: gradle4.0 is pretty old. try with gradle 6

Comment: @Laura Liparulo - I tried with gradle 6.6.1 but same issue. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: this guy also got the issue https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/1904

Comment: i am using jdk 14 and i can´t get the constructors. i think it´s bugged

Comment: if you upgrade to JDK 14 you can use Records instead of the lombok project... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61306802/lombok-getter-setter-vs-java-14-record

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to stay at JDK 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove any references to static imports involving code generated by lombok. In my case, I had:

```
import static com.example.car.dto.CarDto.CarDtoBuilder;
```

`CarDtoBuilder` was generated via lombok `@Builder` on the `CarDto` class. Once resolved, the other lobmok compile related issues such as `log` symbol not found (created by `@Slf4j`) go away.

Comment: thanks, this solved my compilation problems

Comment: This worked for me as well. Is this a bug with Lombok?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see your `lombok-plugin` configuration on your build.gradle file.

I had to setup lombok on my project for gradle 4.10.3 and this is what I did:

```java
group 'io.metadata'
version '1.11-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

project.ext.set("spring.boot.version", "2.2.6.RELEASE")
project.ext.set("spring.core.version", "5.2.5.RELEASE")

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("io.freefair.gradle:lombok-plugin:5.0.0-rc4")
    }
}

subprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'io.freefair.lombok'
}
```

Check the `apply plugin: 'io.freefair.lombok'` and the dependencies defined for it on `buildscript`.

Note that I am using multi module project but either way you can use lombok plugin and `apply` it.

It is not mandatory to use lombok-plugin but it works very well and it's easy to do. You can follow the documentation here:
https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/io.freefair.lombok

Comment: I get an error trying to use that plugin: `An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'io.freefair.lombok', version: '5.1.1']
Failed to apply plugin [class 'io.freefair.gradle.plugins.lombok.LombokBasePlugin']
Could not generate a proxy class for class io.freefair.gradle.plugins.lombok.LombokExtension.
org/gradle/api/provider/MapProperty`

Comment: @user8297969 try with a lower version (the one I posted in the answer), you are using latest plugin version but your gradle is 4.10.3

Comment: I'll try but I'm not sure why my other projects work without the plugin.I also don't mind using Gradle 6 or some other more recent version. Your post says it's using 4.10.3. Which  gradle version would you like for me try?

Comment: @user8297969 well... it's always nice to use the latest versions. Bear in mind that if you use gradle 4.10.3 you will need the lombok plugin compatible with that version. In my answer I posted gradle `4.10.3` with the compatible pluging `5.0.0-rc4`. You can use my this configuration since I know it works (i'm using it), once you make it work you can upgrade gradle/plugin to the latest version.

Comment: I've tried using the latest Gradle version and it allows the `plugins { id "iofreefair.lombok" version "5.1.1"}`. But I get same compile errors. I'm using `plugins` so not sure how to use `apply plugin`. That gives me an error.

Comment: @user8297969 try using the config I provided in the answer. Gradle `4.10.3` plugin `5.0.0-rc4` and the legacy configuration.

Comment: I've tried but I get errors. I'm using `plugins` and it doesn't seem to like `apply plugin`. It also give me an error on `buildscript`. I'm just not sure how to modify my file to do this. I'm not using subprojects and I have other plugins that I need to apply.

Comment: @user8297969 can you check with this https://codeshare.io/aVbDYz

Comment: `See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.3/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block for information on the plugins {} block
 @ line 38, column 1.
   buildscript {
   ^
1 error`

Comment: @user8297969 the error says you have to move buildscript to the top. I updated the link.

Comment: I tried that but then I get error at `apply plugin: 'io.freefair.lombok` that states `Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.3-bin.zip'.
Build file 'C:\Users\user\eclipse-workspace\car-proj\build.gradle' line: 50
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'car-proj'.
Failed to apply plugin [class 'io.freefair.gradle.plugins.lombok.LombokBasePlugin']
Could not generate a proxy class for class io.freefair.gradle.plugins.lombok.LombokExtension.
org/gradle/api/provider/MapProperty`

Comment: @user8297969 alright, it seems a gradle version vs plugin version issue. If you got to the plugin documentation https://docs.freefair.io/gradle-plugins/ go to the version you use, then reference and check the System Requirements. It seems the plugin version use at least gradle 6.2. You just have to use the right plugin version compatible with your gradle version.
https://docs.freefair.io/gradle-plugins/5.0.0-rc4/reference/#_system_requirements

Comment: Thanks for spending time with me on this. I really appreciate this!  I've tried Gradle 6.6.1. When I do that, I don't get the build.gradle issue but I still get the compile errors in my OP where it looks like lombok is not used. This happens when I issue `gradle bootJar`

Comment: @user8297969 latest version of gradle will require latest version of the plugin and both will need a specific configuration that you build.gradle will need. Don't use latest version, try/search with lower version like gradle 6.2, 5.3 or 4.10 and search the apropiate plugin version. There isn't complexity behind this, just proper config. Unfortunately I have to leave but try with those well tested gradle versions. BTW try building the project with `gradle build`

Comment: OK. Thanks. Per [this](https://docs.freefair.io/gradle-plugins/5.0.0-rc4/reference/#_system_requirements), `Unless otherwise noted, all plugins require at least Java 8 and are targeted at Gradle 6.2.`. So I tried 6.2. Still get same compilation issues. I've tried 4.10 too and even 5.3. All same issue. I'm leaning towards removing lombok :(. But I'm not sure what else to do...

Comment: Turns out it was a static import issue. See my answer below. Thanks again for your help. It turns out that I don't need freefair plugin. It's still great to know about it. +1 for all your help.

Comment: @user8297969 great to know, did you use the lombok plugin?

Comment: No. The lombok plugin wasn't necessary.