How does Lombok use internal API's without requiring the end-user to export them?
I'm trying to make an annotation processor similar to Lombok but the issue I'm getting is all projects that use my processor as a library require for jvm arguments to export / open the internal JVM libs. How can I use the internal API's without any other projects needing them?
I have tried to

Use the tools.jar instead of adding jvm exports
Tried to open the libs instead of exporting them
just tried a bunch of random  things to try get it to work

Right now, any projects using my lib require the following in their build.gradle.
compileJava {
    options.fork = true
    options.forkOptions.jvmArgs += [
            '--add-exports', 'jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED',
            '--add-exports', 'jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED',
            '--add-exports', 'jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED',
            '--add-exports', 'jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED',
            '--add-exports', 'jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED',
            '--add-exports', 'jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED',
            '--add-exports', 'jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED',
            '--add-exports', 'jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED',
            '--add-exports', 'jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED'
    ]
}


have you looked at how the annotationProcessor stansa works? see an example of how it is used for lombok here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53212406/1725871 maybe your implementation needs to overload some configuration

Not sure, all that post says is that the new lombok doesn't require a plugin which is what I'm trying to replicate and can't find a way to do.

To do it, you need to mess around a bit with the internal API and call the function that is called when the param is provided to open the API. If anyone wants an example of how to do this, it is here
Note: This code will not work after JDK26 or maybe even before that.
Disclaimer: This code was written by me

When linking to your own code on Stack Overflow, you should always disclose affiliation.

Is that good or should I add something more

Thank you for editing your answer. I think it's fine given these guidelines. Nevertheless, it is typically recommended to include the (important parts of the) code inside the answer using a [code block] (as your answer also works without having the link, this is probably not necessary but recommended).

Also, note that many of the methods (including objectFieldOffset, putBoolean and putBooleanVolatile which you used) in Unsafe may be deprecated in the near future.

Will update if that happens anytime soon.

@dan1st I reread the code and it seems Lombok overcomplicated the hell out of it, I managed to do it with just a bit of reflection.

What Java version are you using? I feel like your code may not work in more recent Java versions like 21.

I was on graal-21
